# Can Pymssql have a secure connection (SSL) to MS SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm making queries from a MS SQL server using Python code (Pymssql library) however I was wondering if there was any way to make the connection secure and encrypt the data being sent from the server to python?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it can.**

You need FreeTDS which supports SSL via OpenSSL. If you happened to use Linux (or Docker on Windows), it's quite easy to install standalone FreeTDS in Debian:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install freetds-bin freetds-dev
pip install pymssql
```

Don't use pymssql with bundled FreeTDS library, it does not support SSL apparently. The bundled library is used when you set env variable `PYMSSQL_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1` before installing pymssql.

Answer (score 2):

pymssql certainly *claims* to be able to work with encrypted connections to the SQL Server (via OpenSSL). One reason why some might believe it to be impossible is that Windows releases of pymssql versions prior to 2.1.2 were shipped with pymssql *statically linked* to FreeTDS for unencrypted connections only.

Starting with version 2.1.2, the Windows release of pymssql is shipped *dynamically linked* to FreeTDS so it can support both unencrypted connections (via FreeTDS alone) or encrypted connections (via FreeTDS and OpenSSL). For details – and an **important update** re: versions 2.1.3 and later – see the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778457/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way, but you could use [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/).

Comment: Are there any good tutorials or wikis on how I can go about using pyodbc?

Comment: @Mo. pyodbc is based on the python's DB-API, so if you know how to use pymssql, then you know this. The main difference is that you need to build the connection string for your database engine, that's the key, you'll be able to include something such as `encrypt=yes`. Check out ConnectionStrings in the official docs: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect SQL server using secured connection using pymssql then you need to provide "secure" syntax in your host..

for e.g.

unsecured connection host : xxx.database.windows.net:1433
secured connection host : xxx.database.secure.windows.net:1443