# Trouble installing pymssql on Windows

Tags: python, windows, openssl, freetds, pymssql

I can't find great support for pymssql installation support on Windows. I'm trying to connect to an enterprise database through another employee's python wrapper. This wrapper requires my installing of pymssql. The [RTFM](http://pymssql.org/en/v2.1.2/freetds.html#windows) on this doesn't have very explicit instructions on the installation process of FreeTDS and OpenSSL.

## Steps to Install

All downloaded files (FreeTDS and OpenSSL) are from the RTFM link mentioned above. There is mention of adding both downloads to a C:\Program Files folder and adding the binaries into the system `PATH`, so I did this:

### FreeTDS

1. Downloaded FreeTDS >> created the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeTDS >> copy/paste contents of FreeTDS download into C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeTDS directory >> added C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeTDS into my system's `PATH`

#### Contents of FreeTDS download:

```
\bin
    \bsqldb.exe
    \bsqldb.exe.manifest
    \bsqlodbc.exe
    ...
    \tsql.exe
\include
    \bkpublic.h
    \cspublic.h
    \cstypes.h
    ...
    \tds_sysdep_public.h
\lib
    \static
        \db-lib.lib
        \iconv.lib
        \libct.lib
        \replacements.lib
        \tds.lib
    \ct.dll
    \ct.dll.manifest
    ...
    \tsodbc.lib
\lib-nossl
(same as \lib)
```

### OpenSSL

2. Downloaded OpenSSL >> created the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL >> copy/paste contents of OpenSSL download into C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL directory >> added C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL into my system's `PATH`

#### Contents of OpenSSL download:

```
\HashInfo.txt
\libeay32.dll
\OpenSSL License.txt
\openssl.exe
\ReadMe.txt
\ssleay32.dll
```

### PYMSSQL

3. Install pymssql through pip: `python -m pip install pymssql` >> then check for install status:

#### Open Python Environment

- run: `import pymssql`
- get: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Super frustrating. Really appreciate any help here!

(unfortunately most everyone I know runs pymssql from Linux and they don't have this problem)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned (briefly) in the pymssql documentation you cited, and also in my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778457/2144390), your Windows `PATH` needs to include the folder(s) where the **DLL files** reside, not the base folder(s) for FreeTDS (and OpenSSL, if required).

So, on my test machine running 32-bit Windows my `PATH` needed to include the "lib-nossl" folder for FreeTDS ...

```
C:\Users\Gord\Downloads\freetds-v0.95.83-win-x86-vs2015\lib-nossl
```

... in order for me to use pymssql 2.1.2 with Python 3.5.1 to establish a non-encrypted connection to my SQL Server.

Comment: Got it working, thanks! I fixed the path directories, made sure I had correct versions of freetds and openssl, then pip installed pymssql. Note: operating system bit version, release version, and software sources are all important factors that should not be overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays I recommend just downloading the version you need from here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql and then installing via below steps.

1. Download the version to want to place on disk, can be Downloads or anywhere you want.  I downloaded pymssql-2.1.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl because I'm using Python 3.8 on Windows 10 64 bit.
2. Navigate to directory where you downloaded or move the file...
3. pip install <pymssql file name>

I didn't have to install anything extra, worked right out of the box.