# Trouble Installing pymssql on Windows 10

Tags: windows, freetds, pymssql

I am trying to install `pymssql` version 2.1.3 into an Anaconda 4.3.0 environment running on windows 10. I have been following the steps outlined to resolve in this post:
[Trouble installing pymssql on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369974/trouble-installing-pymssql-on-windows).

However I am still getting this error:

> C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlfront.h': No such file or
>   directory   error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I downloaded the freetds file structure (ver 1.00) and copied the directories to 
`c:\\Program Files (x86)\freetds as well as in c:\\users\{me}\AppData\Local\freetds`.

Did I load the freetds incorrectly?

Also note -- I have tried to install using the wheel file - pymssql-2.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl but this is failing with an error:

> Permission denied: 'C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymssql.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'

I am using pip vers 9.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried installing using the wheel as an admin user? Make sure you get the correct 32 or 64 bit version.

Comment: I am an admin user but when installing from Visual Studio am prompted to "Elevate to Admin".  I will look for a way to sign in as admin before installing the wheel.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.Try to install pymssql using latest wheel file  [Download pymssql wheel file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql)