# Why can I connect to Azure MS SQL with tsql but not pymssql?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pymssql

Where I am today:

```
TDSVER=7.3 tsql -H example.database.windows.net -U me -D ExampleDB -p 1433 -P notreallymypassword
```

This does not:

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> pymssql.connect('example.database.windows.net', user='me', password='notreallymypassword', database='ExampleDB', tds_version='7.3')
```

It fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 577, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:6214)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1704, in _mssql._tds_ver_str_to_constant (_mssql.c:18845)
_mssql.MSSQLException: unrecognized tds version: 7.3
```

Okay. Well, that's... strange. So I went back and tried the `tsql` using `TDSVER=7.2`, which seemed to work fine.

Trying to connect with `tds_version='7.2'` gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 637, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:6581)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1630, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException (_mssql.c:17524)
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (datawhse.database.
windows.net:1433)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (datawhse.database.windo
ws.net:1433)\n')
```

So, what gives?

**Update 1:**
pyodbc *also* fails to connect:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('SERVER=example.database.windows.net;Driver=FreeTDS;UID=me@example.database.windows.net;PWD=notmyrealpassword;'
, ansi=True)
```

My ~/.odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description     = MS SQL driver
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Setup           = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.0
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.0
UsageCount      = 1
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
Trace           = Yes
```

And this output:

```
⚘ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/me/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Comment: What versions of `pymssql` and `freetds` are you running?

Comment: Also, see Gord's answer here about SSL/TLS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040536/pymssql-on-windows-can-connect-to-local-sql-server-but-not-to-azure-sql

Comment: @FlipperPA I'm not on the windows (CentOS), so I'm not sure that applies [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt694094(v=sql.1).aspx) also doesn't seem to mention SSL/TLS

Comment: ( cc: @FlipperPA ) - *"This MSDN article also doesn't seem to mention SSL/TLS"* - The article specifically refers to Ubuntu, which ships with openssl and is apparently configured so that pip can find it when building pymssql. It seems that the same may not always be true for CentOS, e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymssql/scOnx0LIlao).

Comment: `pip` doesn't build `pymssql` - it uses the pre-built wheels. At least it downloaded wheels when **I** installed it.

Comment: @GordThompson That person was having problems installing pymssql - it installed just fine from me, using the wheel. I'm also unable to connect via pyodbc which I'm pretty sure has SSL support because we use it+psycopg2 to connect to postgresql which also requires SSL, and that works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it seems that there are a lot of variations that can come into play, as often seems to be the case with Linux. I know for sure that after I got FreeTDS working with SSL on Ununtu 16.04 and then did a plain `pip install pymssql` I got the "wheel" version and it *did not* work with SSL connections. I had to use the `pip install --no-binary` option to get pymssql built from source as mentioned in my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39395549/2144390).

Comment: @GordThompson how can I verify that it's built with SSL? Because I definitely installed from source (had to add the freetds-devel library)

Comment: See what `tsql -C` tells you.

Comment: Well, tsql was, but apparently pymssql's wheel isn't?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the way things stand right now. I believe that for a while they shipped the Windows versions pre-compiled with static binding to FreeTDS components that did not include SSL (because of OpenSSL licensing), but the Linux versions were built from source. Now it seems that all flavours are shipped as wheels without SSL support (again, probably because of the OpenSSL licensing), perhaps just for consistency.

Comment: Looking at the license for openssl I hope that's not it - it looks like a fairly permissive license!

Comment: The whole licensing thing is still quite a mystery to me. My comments were based [this page](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.htm) where it says "Unlike FreeTDS, OpenSSL does not use the LGPL. Please read the OpenSSL license before distributing binaries compiled with this option."

Comment: _Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *    distribution._ Which looks like it just needs that document in the distributed materials. Of course maybe someone didn't want to deal with that *shrugs*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Gord was right: The problem was that `pymssql` wheel *does not have SSL bindings*.

I uninstalled it:

```
python -m pip uninstall pymssql
```

Then installed it from source:

```
python -m pip install --no-binary pymssql pymssql
```

This required me to install a few dependencies. But now I can connect with

```
pymssql.connect('example.database.windows.net',
                user='me', 
                password='notreallymypassword', 
                database='ExampleDB',
                tds_version='7.2')
```

Answer (score -2):

Your connection string doesn't look right. It should be something like:

```
pymssql.connect(server='example.database.windows.net', user='me@example', password='notreallymypassword', database='ExampleDB')
```

Note that in your example call to `connect()`, you are missing a `server=` parameter; you only had the full server name.

Comment: My username *is* just `me` - that's what `tsql` has and works. Using strace I can verify that I'm actually connecting to the Azure server and receiving data... though it's probably just the error message. Regardless, I changed it to `me@example`, and added the `server=` (which [doesn't appear to be necessary](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#functions)) and it still didn't work)

Comment: `server` is first argument so `pymssql.connect('example.database.windows.net'...)` and `pymssql.connect(server='example.database.windows.net'...)` is the same