# Why can I connect to Azure SQL with tsql but not pymssql in centOS?

Tags: azure, ssl, centos, freetds, pymssql

I am able to connect to Azure SQL Server using T-SQL like below.

```
tsql -H testdb.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U testuser -P testpass -D testdb
```

I am not able to connect when I use pymssql.

```
>>import pymssql
>>connection = pymssql.connect(server='testdb', user='testuser@testdb', password='testpass', database='testdb')
```

This fails with an error:

> Unexpected error: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
>   File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
>   File "_mssql.pyx", line 637, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.**init** (_mssql.c:6581)
>   File "_mssql.pyx", line 1630, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException (_mssql.c:17524)
>   _mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (testdb:1433)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./testdb_Azure_Test.py", line 13, in 
>   connection = pymssql.connect(server='testdb', user='testuser@testdb', password='testpass', database='testdb')
>   File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (testdb:1433)\n')

After checking the same type of problem 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129928/why-can-i-connect-to-azure-ms-sql-with-tsql-but-not-pymssql?noredirect=1&lq=1). I followed all the mentioned steps and installed the SSL from openssl.org site because centOS doesn't have the SSL bundled with it.

I installed the SSL(OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013) from openssl.org and freeTDS version (FreeTDS 0.95.19) and using python3.5.

When I check with tsql -C it showed OpenSSL= YES and TDS Version 7.3.

```
    Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                                Version: freetds v0.95
                 freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
         MS db-lib source compatibility: no
            Sybase binary compatibility: no
                          Thread safety: yes
                          iconv library: yes
                            TDS version: 7.3
                                  iODBC: no
                               unixodbc: no
                  SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                               Kerberos: no
                                OpenSSL: yes
                                 GnuTLS: no
```

I still phasing the same problem, Not sure what I am doing wrong. Is the version I used for SSL is old one do I need to install any new version.

I know it is working for most of the after installing the SSL, Please advise I am struggling with this issue for long time. Please advise what I am missing and what steps and versions I need to follow to make Azure to work.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: So after you installed OpenSSL did you reinstall pymssql from source?

Comment: Yes, I followed the steps mentioned in earlier thread. First uninstalled (python -m pip uninstall pymssql) the pymssql than reinstalled from source(python -m pip install --no-binary pymssql pymssql). Not sure how to check, it installed updated version with new build on SSL.

Comment: when connecting using pymssql still it's defaulting the TDS version to 7.1 as earlier, not taking from freeTDS.conf file(TDS 7.3). When I used TSQL it is taking the TDS Version from freeTDS.conf file.

Comment: After uninstalling the 'pymssql' and reinstalling using the below option got the below message. #/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install --no-binary pymssql pymssql
Collecting pymssql
Using cached pymssql-2.1.3.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for pymssql, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: pymssql
Running setup.py install for pymssql ... done
Successfully installed pymssql-2.1.3

Comment: @Srinivas have you solve this ?