# Encrypted database connection from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymssql

What are the steps required to configure SQLAlchemy with SSL support on RedHat Linux so I can connect to a MS SQL Server instance that requires an encrypted connection?

Comment: Fairly certain that it depends on your DB-API driver in use.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - I'm using pymssql

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724427/can-pymssql-have-a-secure-connection-ssl-to-ms-sql-server, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395548/how-to-configure-pymssql-with-ssl-support-on-ubuntu, and http://pymssql.org/en/stable/freetds.html. You don't configure SQLAlchemy with SSL support, but pymssql.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `pymssql` (as suggested by the tag on your question) then you'll need to build it from source in order for it to support SSL connections. The process will be similar to the one described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39395548/2144390).

Alternatively, you may find it easier to use `pyodbc` along with Microsoft's [SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).