# How can Python3.7 connect SQL Server with TLS1.2?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, tls1.2

SQL Server has upgraded TLS to 1.2 now, and my python connection pop up failure cause `pymssql`does not support.
I want to know whether there are any module to support SQL Server connection with TLS 1.2 now?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724427/can-pymssql-have-a-secure-connection-ssl-to-ms-sql-server

Comment: I found that pymssql has supported TLS1.2, I only need to re-pyinstaller the code, it will work normally.

Comment: can you please explain to me more how to do this? perhaps as an answer?